# chainlink functions with geth

Tags: chainlink, go-ethereum

am trying to integrate chainlink functions to do some computations in my system ,however am using geth client , and I can t find anything in the documentation on how to set or configure these  functions with local geth network

I only see docs on how to set it on mumbai

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink Functions uses a decentralized network of node operators, all of whom connect their oracles to public blockchains using their own choice of RPC provider (ie, Geth client), in order to maximize decentralization. Functions oracles cannot connect to your locally-run blockchain environment.

What goal are you trying to to accomplish? If you're just looking to write some basic test dara to a private blockchain network using Chainlink, I'd recommend running your own Chainlink node, pointing it to your local Geth network's RPC URL within the Chainlink node's EVM settings, and using Chainlink's Any API functionality (also called Direct Requests or Basic Requests) to make your request.

Best of luck, and I hope that helps!

Comment: I have data stored on ipfs , i need to do some computations on it and i saw that chainlink functions allow this , also am locally running blockchain

Comment: You cannot use Functions to access a locally-run blockchain network - you'll need to spin up your own Chainlink node and point it to your local blockchain's RPC URL in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your response Derek , I launched my own chainlink node , however I didn t know how to create a subscription since the subcription ui that allows us to create subs is only available for the supported networks (mainnets , sepolia..), Also , for link contract I deployed it , but for functionRouter contract I couldn t find it and didn t know what to put in donId .

Comment: You won't be able to easily launch your own Functions network, as running Functions as a node operator is restricted to official node operators only. What I was suggesting is using the Direct Request model to request your data. You can read more about how to host this sort of request using Chainlink's Any API guide here: https://docs.chain.link/any-api/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Angela - the support networks indicate what (public) networks are supported [1].  There are several public chains supported -- not just Mumbai. Can you please drop a link to where it says only Mumbai?

Also, not clear if by Geth Client you're using that as a client to access a public chain (as Derek indicated)? Or do you mean locally running blockchain network (you say "local geth network").  If it's the latter, then that is "disconnected" from public chains and so cannot interact with Chainlink Oracle Nodes as your chain is running only on your machine.

[1] https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/supported-networks